# Auto refresh not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I try to draw circular gauge using `jQuery` and `circularchart` and I'm able to make it.

I want the `setInterval()` function of javascript to auto-refresh the value so that the gauge value keep update by itself without manual refresh.

But the `setinterval()` function is not working at all.

I don't want to refresh the whole page or the body of html.

I just want to refresh the particular `circleChart#0` function.

Your help is needed.

This is circle.html

```
<body>
  <div class="circleChart" id="0"></div>
  <div class="circleChart" id="1" data-value="77"></div>
  <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='jquery-1.12.4.min.js') }}"></script>
  <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='circleChart.js') }}"></script>
  <script>
    $(".circleChart#1").circleChart();
    $(".circleChart#0").circleChart({
      size: 200,
      value: {{temperature}},
      text: 0,
      onDraw: function(el, circle) {
        circle.text(Math.round(circle.value) + "'C");
      }
    });


    setInterval(function() {
      $("#0").circleChart({
        value: {{temperature}},
        onDraw: function(el, circle) {
          circle.text(Math.round(circle.value) + "'C");
        }
      });
    }, 2000);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is my python code (main.py)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)


import os
import glob
import time

os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')
os.system('modprobe w1-therm')

base_dir = '/sys/bus/w1/devices/'
device_folder = glob.glob(base_dir + '28*')[0]
device_file = device_folder + '/w1_slave'

def read_temp_raw():
    f = open(device_file, 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    return lines

def read_temp():

    lines = read_temp_raw()
    while lines[0].strip()[-3:] != 'YES':
        time.sleep(0.2)
        lines = read_temp_raw()
        equals_pos = lines[1].find('t=')
        if equals_pos != -1:
        temp_string = lines[1][equals_pos+2:]
        temp_c = float(temp_string) / 1000.0
        temp_f = temp_c * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32.0
        return temp_c, temp_f

 @app.route("/")
 def main():
      temperature , humidity = read_temp()
      templateData = {
        'temperature' : temperature,
        'humidity': humidity
         }
      return render_template('circle.html', **templateData)

 if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=True)
```

Comment: @MilanChheda Are you sure you didn't edit out some template markup from the code, or the possible error source?

Comment: Yes @Teemu Nothing removed. Just formatted.

Comment: I have temperature sensor connected to my raspberry pi. So I test whether the circular gauge value on my website  update or not when i place my sensor in hot and ice water. And the gauge value update only when i manually refresh the page.@JamesThorpe

Comment: @MilanChheda `{{temperature}}` is a template variable, which you broke with your "formatting".

Comment: Where have you defined `temperature` ??

Comment: Apologies. it got converted into JS.

Comment: there is some issue with `circle.text` also. I think you need to keep the initialization object for `circle` first then use.

Comment: @atulquest93 What you mean bro? Can you elaborate on it?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `{{temperature}}` is some kind of template variable, those are (typically) only evaluated once when generating the page from your template.

You will need some kind of AJAX call to fetch the updated temperature value.

Comment: Sorry bro, but I can 't understand. But why the templates variable value is update when I refresh the page manually? So the setInterval() function wont work with template variable is it?